# What is the etymology of butyraceous?

Tags: etymology

I recently learned the word *butyraceous* and immediately fell in love with it, likely because of my love affair with butter. A quick Google search did not give me anything for its etymology, though. I guess that it is similar to the etymology for the word *butter*, but the "*-yracious*" suffix (if that is what it is) confuses me.

So what is the etymology of the word *butyraceous*? Where does it come from and what is the history of its use?

Comment: http://www.myetymology.com/english/butyraceous.html, and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-aceous

Comment: There are hundreds of words that utilize the -aceous suffix, 83 of which [are listed here](http://wordinfo.info/unit/11/ip:1). OED's "first use" entry (1669) says *Milk [has] three parts ... **Butyraceous, Serous**, and **Caseous***, but my Google Chrome spellchecker whinges about the first and last of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As terdon and FumbleFingers indicate in their comments, *butyraceous* comes from the Latin word *butyrum* (butter) and the suffix *-aceous* ("characterized by" or "of the nature of"). It appears in Samuel Johnson's dictionary of 1756, with the definition "Having the qualities of butter."

Google's Ngram Viewer shows [an interesting graph](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=butyraceous&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=) of the term's usage, indicating that *butyraceous* appeared proportionately most frequently in the years between 1730 and and 1900. Of course in the 1700s, one occurrence constituted a much more significant proportion of total usage than it does today.

The first occurrence that Google Books finds from 1600 forward is in Peter Shaw, *Philosophical Principles of Universal Chemistry* (1730), a book in which the term appears four times:

> But the Greatest part of Benjamin [a resin] sublimes in the form of Flowers; after which comes off also a thick or **butyraceous** kind of matter.

and

> To this ball must again be added a little of the Mercury that was squeezed from it; or so much as to reduce it to the consistence of a somewhat soft and **butyraceous** mass;

and

> Or else without such a previous digestion, the mixture is directly put into a small glass Retort, with a very wide neck, and slowly urged with proper degrees of Fire in a Sand-Furnace; by which means the acid Spirit of Salt contain'd in the *Mercury-Sublimate*, seizes the *Regulus*, imbibes, dissolves, and thence carries it over the helm with itself; and at the same time gives it a thick or **butyraceous** consistence, whence 'tis called by the name of *Butter of Antimony*.

and

> The Production of this Operation is called *philosophical Gold* on account of its being so highly attenuated, subtilized, and brought to such an *impalpable Powder*, that when mix'd in this form along with fresh *Mercury*, 'tis immediately dissolved thereby; after the same manner, to illustrate the thing by a gross example, that Leaf-gold is more expeditiously and easily ground into a fine **butyraceous** amalgam with common Mercury, than such Gold as is only granulated or used in the form of coarser Filings.

The other six occurrences prior to 1764 that Google Books finds are likewise in scientific publications and appear in discussions of chemistry, botany, or medicine.

The first figurative or purely literary occurrence of *butyraceous* that I've been able to find in Google Books search results is from "Personal Recollections of the Late Mrs. Hemans," by H.F.C., in *The Museum of Foreign Literature and Science*, vol. 27 (1835):

> I had such a levee yesterday morning, I was as much inclined to run away from them all, as from the Bishop and Dean, and sofa-table, and Chinese puzzles of old. ——— and ——— called upon me—what a ***butyraceous***-looking pair they are!

Comment: The way it is used in the last quote is quite interesting. I thought to impress my geeky friends and use it in place of "sweet" when commenting on how nice or pleasant something is. Excellent post.